# How to get Last Month interval with MSSQL in January

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

How can this code be fixed, so it doesn't break in January? I believe this part is the bug:

`(Month(Getdate()) - 1`

SQL:

```
AND UOnline.maxstamp > dbo.Udf_converttotimeinterval(
                           Cast(Cast(Year(Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4))
                           + RIGHT('0' + Cast((Month(Getdate()) - 1) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
                           + RIGHT('0' + Cast(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME), 'ss')

AND UOnline.maxstamp < dbo.Udf_converttotimeinterval(
                           Cast(Cast(Year(Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4))
                           + RIGHT('0' + Cast(Month(Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
                           + RIGHT('0' + Cast(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME), 'ss')
```

The User Defined Function, if anyone needs it:

```
USE [XXX]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/**** UDF_ConvertToTimeInterval ****/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_ConvertToTimeInterval](@VALUE DATETIME, 
@INVERVALTYPE VARCHAR(2))
RETURNS BIGINT WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
BEGIN
    IF @INVERVALTYPE IS NOT NULL
        Begin           
            If Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'S' OR Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'SS'
                RETURN DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1970', 101), 
                                        CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE, 101))
            If Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'MI' OR Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'N'
                RETURN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1970', 101), 
                                        CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE, 101))
            If Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'H' OR Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'HH'
                RETURN DATEDIFF(HOUR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1970', 101), 
                                      CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE, 101))
            If Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'D' OR Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'DD'
                RETURN DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1970', 101), 
                                     CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE, 101))
            If Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'M' OR Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'MM'
                RETURN DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1970', 101), 
                                       CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE, 101))
            If Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'Y' OR Upper(@INVERVALTYPE) = 'YY'
                RETURN DATEDIFF(YEAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1970', 101), 
                                      CONVERT(DATETIME, @VALUE, 101))
            Else
                Return Null
        end     
    Else
        Return null
    Return null
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply substracting from a Month / Day is usually a bad idea... instead of

```
(Month(Getdate()) - 1
```

try the following

```
MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
```